# How to COMPLETELY uninstall Visual Studio Code from Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, uninstall, visual-studio-code

Seriously, it's hyper frustrating that after 35 years making software, Microsoft doesn't knows yet how to uninstall a program

I'm trying to uninstall Visual Studio Code, yes, this question is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47689536/uninstall-visual-studio-code-in-windows but answers are partial and incorrect.

I have done, uninstall using the control panel. Then uninstall everything in %appdata%\code, then deleting %USERPROFILE%.vs... (it's different path if you use visual studio code or visual studio code insiders)

No matter what, after I install the program again, it will show my environment just as it was before doing all this.

So, how do you uninstall completely, to do a fresh VS Code installation without installing Windows 10 from scratch?

Comment: The one I'm trying to install is Insiders. HKU/Software/Microsoft/...? I don't see it. Why can't control panel uninstall just... uninstalls?

Comment: :D. I am totally with you there bro. for 20 years. uninstall, reinstall  and 99% of the time it solves absolutely freaking nothing because of traces left in the OS. incredibly frustrating

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Here are the default paths where Visual Studio Code Insider saves files:

- Installation path:

```
"%LocalAppData%\Programs\Microsoft VS Code Insiders"
```

- User settings and preferences:

```
"%UserProfile%\.vscode-insiders"
"%AppData%\Code - Insiders"
"%AppData%\Visual Studio Code - Insiders"
```

- Shortcut folder:

```
"%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Visual Studio Code - Insiders"
```

These folder save the last user session and settings/preferences. Delete those to remove old settings/preferences. If you are concerned about the remaining files after installation you may use VSCode from the portable ZIP files. Here are the *direct download links* extracted from [VSCode alternative downloads](https://code.visualstudio.com/#alt-downloads):

- 32 bit stable: https://vscode-update.azurewebsites.net/latest/win32-archive/stable
- 32 bit insider: https://vscode-update.azurewebsites.net/latest/win32-archive/insider
- 64 bit stable: https://vscode-update.azurewebsites.net/latest/win32-x64-archive/stable
- 64 bit insider: https://vscode-update.azurewebsites.net/latest/win32-x64-archive/insider

Comment: I didn't noticed there's a portable edition. I think I'll use it and "sync" all the settings using dropbox, thanks a lot!

Comment: @luisfer Try this for portable mode: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/portable

Comment: Worth noting that even portable mode leaves trace files behind. Mostly has to do with Electron bugs.

Answer (score 24):

After uninstalling vscode, remove:

- `%UserProfile%\.vscode`
- `%AppData%\Code`
- `%LocalAppData%\Programs\Microsoft VS Code`

Comment: Thank you this was exactly what I was looking for, it is short and clear

Answer (score 2):

I was having the exact issues...

My reason for trying to do a full uninstall of Visual Studio Code was because I was having issues writing code, especially HTML codes. When I type at least 2 letters, the cursor automatically skips to the end of the page and all subsequent letters that I type is written after the HTML close tag.

```
...
    <p> this i </p>
 </body>
</html>s only to show the problem I was having with Visual Studio Code
```

I also tried uninstalling VS Code but everything remains the same and I kept having the same issues. Unlike other softwares, the uninstall application for VS Code doesn't uninstall also the components (extensions and settings). It only removes the VS Code software.

What I did was to permanently delete any and all folder that has "VS" or "Visual Studio". You also need to check "Microsoft" folders because "VS Code" folders can be found there. After doing all that you definitely want to delete a folder with the name ".vscode" and you can find in your "home" folder. The reason why your workspace remains the same is because all your previous extensions and settings are stored in that folder.

[.vscode Extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/82QpR.jpg)

I sincerely hope I've been helpful to someone.

Answer (score 1):

**As an addition to the approved message, you also might want to get rid of a registry key left by the installer if you can't access the uninstaller program:**

`Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{771FD6B0-FA20-440A-A002-3B3BAC16DC50}_is1`
[(source)](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/109518#issuecomment-717965782)

Once it's removed, installer will ask you about specifying an installation folder again – usually this does not happen when removing everything *but* abovementioned registry key.

This might be helpful if you are forced to perform a full wipe of your current VSCode installation. ("forced to" – for example, when previous installation was on a faulty HDD, or it got intentionally plugged out for a reason)

Comment: That was indeed necessary for me, but it made the VS Code taskbar icon disappear. I re-enabled it using this answer: [VSCode icon in task bar is blank](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65900895/3002584).

Answer (score 0):

It also happened with me, Seriously it is frustrating. So to uninstall it completely you have to follow these steps(any Windows OS):

1. Press Windows+r
2. Type %appdata%\local\Programs
3. Go to Microsoft VS Code and permanently delete this file
4. ----------Done-----------
5. Now install again.

I think it should work for you also. If not then again follow these above steps and do and at the time of installing click the checkbox to Don't create a Start Menu Folder. And then install it.

-----Try these above steps, it will help you.

Comment: Only have a "Code" folder in AppData/Local. Do not forget to delete the ".vscode" folder in your user directory.

Answer (score 0):

so i think this work but you can go to the file where your vscode is installed or just `right click` the app and `open file location` and then you will see an application called `unins000` just click that and uninstall it :).

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks.