# Visual Studio Code React Native IntelliSense not working

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense

As the title states: Visual Studio Code React Native IntelliSense is not working. I have installed all the possible extensions for React Native and followed many suggested steps to fix the issue, but none of them helped.
I have uninstalled and reinstalled the VSCode with a fresh download.

Installed extensions:
[image]

EDIT:
Steps I have already tried:
--npm install typings -g and then  typings install dt~react-native (I had to delete --global,because it threw an error saying to drop it)
--changing the jsconfig.json and tsconfig.json
--installed this: https://gist.github.com/ZainaliSyed/36ebbf538aa4c96f3a14f15f893199a7

In VSCode at the bottom the language is set to JavaScript.
Also Intellisense didn't work for typescript as well.

Comment: it would be helpful for you to include the steps you've already tried in your question

Comment: @mael' I have edited my question,please take a look at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it. I have completely uninstalled VSCode following this:
https://superuser.com/a/1380253/1054629

Answer (score 0):

Simply install `npm i -D @types/react-native` & it give auto suggestions to you about react native

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The way I just solve this was check the `tsconfig.json` that you have. Make sure if you have any "paths" or any exports types/interface in any types don't conflict with any `HTMLElement` types.

If you don't have one, init it inside the root:

```
npx tsc --init
```

and make sure to add this under `compilerOptions`:

```
{ "jsx":"react-native" }
```